# PHP: reading xls with phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am having trouble reading the .xls file. Values ​​are read as null and in unknown characters. The file is downloaded from an ftp server and it comes protected

```
$path = 'doc/20180719-ASK FIDC_EVOLUCAO_COTA.xls';
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path);

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$reader->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
//$reader->setDelimiter("\t");

$excel = $reader->load($path);

var_dump($excel);
echo $inputFileType;

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setUseBOM(true);
$writer->save('data.csv');

echo 'File saved to csv format';
```

The converted file looks like the image:

[image]

Comment: What does "it comes protected" mean?

Comment: protected from editing, read-only and I can not unprotect it

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem if you're using current PHPExcel. Are you sure the encoding you specified is correct?